# Filesystem Module in Parse Web Server

Tags: javascript, pdf, parse-platform, web-hosting, fs

I am currently attempting to use Parse Web Hosting to setup a website for my iOS application. I am attempting to show a PDF file in the web browser located within my website directory. I am using express and heres whats going on so far

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

app.get('/terms', function(request, response){
  fs.readFile("/public/terms_conditions_hotspot.pdf", function (err,data){
     response.contentType("application/pdf");
     response.render(data);
  });
});

app.listen();
```

So when I navigate to `mysite.parseapp.com/terms`, I get a 500 error.

But to make sure everything is setup correctly, I used Parse's boilerplate code to render a hello message when you navigate to `mysite.parseapp.com/hello`.

```
app.get('/hello', function(request, response) {
  response.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
});
```

This seems to work fine. Anyone know what the issue is?

My goal is migrating my Django Web app to using Parse Web Hosting instead mainly because Parse supports SSL and supplies free certs, which makes building this application cheaper (free). Although, my Django Web App's purpose is to deal with Stripe Connect redirects and used oAuth2, which may be problematic with the migration, seeing as Parse may not support certain modules or whatever. I just feel Parse is very limited with their services but I am anxious to see what I can do with it.

***EDIT***

So I ran `console.log(error)` and it returned:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'readFile'
```

readFile is definitely a method that fs ('filesystem') contains. So maybe the module 'fs' in Parse isn't up to date or refers to a different module?

What the deuce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse doesn't appear to use NodeJS (fs is a Node module) even though they offer Express.

See: https://www.parse.com/questions/loading-nodejs-packages-to-cloud-code